# Regarding specific edit

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, specific-question

One of my [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6367264) had a suggested edit and I approved it. I am still having a feeling that there wasn't a reason to make that edit. It was addition of a relevant tag. The question was quite old. The user is editing many questions. All seem to be correct but still I am confused.

Can anyone look and share whether such edits are ok?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That tag is not particularly relevant. To be fair, your question's title was a bit confusing - the error you encountered isn't a runtime error in the normal sense, but rather a CodeChef error. Still, the editor should have known better, and so should you by now. Unfortunately, some folks like to go around adding tags based on keywords in the posts, regardless of whether they actually pertain to the *question*.

There's a rejection reason for these sorts of superfluous tag edits:

[image: irrelevant tags]

Next time you see someone adding a pointless tag to one of your questions, just reject it.

Answer (score 0):

You should have rejected it. The rejection reason fits perfectly:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

With enough of those rejections, the user gets automatically banned from suggesting further edits for a while.

Comment: The part that confused me was "easier to find". The tags are used for search. Right?

Comment: Yes, but that tag is too... broad. I don't think it should exist to begin with.